# Dryer heating element repair?

Tags: dryer

[image: broken dryer heating element]

A [dryer heating element](https://www.ebay.com/itm/133759018719) has snapped: is there any reason why it can not be bridged via soldering or a butt splice?

Kenmore Model 110.66642500

[image: dryer identification tag]

Comment: Many reasons.  Can see this question for why.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10218/my-dryer-heating-element-broke-in-two-can-i-just-wrap-the-ends-together?rq=1

Comment: This isn't a part you can just solder together. Go to the scrap yard or just talk to a scrapper and obtain a 'new' one. Kenmore dryers are very common.

Comment: Consider how hot the element gets, and what would happen to the solder joint. In emergencies, I've used a steel sleeve, compressed onto the wires... but it can short to the container and won't last long.

Comment: Also note that a full kit of replacement parts, new, usually includes a number of safety sensors, is not particularly expensive, available online, as your link indicates.